# Why controller not render twig template

Tags: php, symfony, template-engine

I have a template (*homepage.html.twig*) in *app/Resources/homepage*.
I'm trying to render this template within the `HomeController` class.

```php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/home", name="homepage")
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function homeAction()
    {
        return $this->render('homepage/homepage.html.twig');
    }
}
```

This is the content of the template.

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Navbar example</h1>
            <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static navbar and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
            <p>
                <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href=# role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Why doesn't rendering the template work?

Comment: All templates in Symfony must be located in app/Resources/views    you must put your template in app/Resources/views/homepage so you can render it successfully

Comment: @paris93 ; We can also put views on our bundle folder: "src/YourBundle/Resources/views".

Comment: yes it's true, but @Rumen puted the template directly in the Ressources file, which will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by putting

```
{% block body %}
{% endblock %}
```

in the base.html.twig